# array replace function not working for me

Tags: php

is there any array replace  function in php ..

in php manual there is a function called array_replace but its not working...

Tell me some example...

for array replace..

Comment: Post your code also to see what/how you are doing it.

Comment: Well `array_replace` works for me... and examples should be found in the manual. Could it be that you use the wrong tool for the job? But unless you tell us **what** you want to do and show some code we cannot help you.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? array_replace() is only available since PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$base = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$replacements = array(0 => "pineapple", 4 => "cherry");
$replacements2 = array(0 => "grape");

$basket = array_replace($base, $replacements, $replacements2);
echo '<pre>' .
print_r($base, true) .
print_r($basket, true) .
'</pre>';
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
)
Array
(
    [0] => grape
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
    [4] => cherry
)
```

the question is: what exactly isnt working for *you*?

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way. Dereferencing:

```
$myarray = array("Peter", "Brian", "Stewart");
$myarray['2'] = "Stewie";

print_r($myarray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Peter
    [1] => Brian
    [2] => Stewie
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember where I found this solution so I cannot give credit to the person who created this alternative array_replace function for Servers who do not have the array_replace function available. It works great and is seamless to add since you would not need to change your existing code that is using the array_replace function.

Edit: found the author. Credit goes to MikevHoenselaar: https://github.com/MikeRogers0/PHP-HTML5-Form-class/issues/4

```
// Fallback function if the PHP Server does not have the array_replace function
if ( !function_exists('array_replace') ) {

    function array_replace() { 
        $array = array();    
        $n = func_num_args(); 

        while ( $n-- >0 ) { 
            $array+=func_get_arg($n); 
        } 
    return $array; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my below real world example so you can better understand array replacement. It refers to a shopping cart stored in session variable. The last line of code replaces the already existing product array with an updated one by dereferencing. **`$_SESSION['cart'][$index] = $product;`**

```
$product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'product_id');
$index = count($_SESSION['cart']);

//if product has not been already in cart
if (!in_array($_POST['product_id'], $product_ids)) {

        $product = array(
            'product_id' => $_POST['product_id'] + 0,
            'product_quantity' => $_POST['product_quantity'] + 0,
            'product_price' => $_POST['product_price'] + 0
        );

        $_SESSION['cart'][++$index] = $product;
}

//if product exists update it's quantity and total price
else {

        $new_quantity = $_POST['product_quantity'] + $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['product_quantity'];
        $new_price = $_POST['product_price'] + $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['product_price'];

        $product = array(
            'product_id' => $_POST['product_id'] + 0,
            'product_quantity' => $new_quantity,
            'product_price' => $new_price
        );

        $_SESSION['cart'][$index] = $product;
    }
}
```